# Do I need a current limiting resistor for MAX383 digital logic?

Tags: resistors, raspberry-pi, opto-isolator

I'm trying to control a MAX383 analog switch using a Raspberry Pi, through an optocoupler (Sharp PC817), to separate digital logic from the analog section.

On the analog side, I will have a bipolar supply (+6, -6V) from a TLE2426 rail splitter.

I want to connect the positive rail to the logic pin on the MAX383, through the optocoupler which would source current to the pin. If my logic is correct, I will also need a pull-down resistor (I assume somewhere in the 100k range would be ok), from the pin to ground.

Question is: do I need to add a current limiting resistor somewhere in there? From the datasheet I see it needs min 2.4V to register a logic high, but there's not max specified, so I assume 6V from the power rail is OK. However, it does state max current to be 1uA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flRsml.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the MAX383 is connected to the positive 6V rail on its Vcc pin then take note of the note underneath the absolute maximum ratings in the data sheet: -

> Note 1: Signals on NC, NO, COM, or **IN** exceeding V+ or V- are clamped
>   by internal diodes. Limit forward diode current to maximum current
>   rating.

This means you are OK because the "IN" input is the digital logic control pin.

You don't need a current limiting resistor but you do need a pull-down as shown on your diagram.

Answer (score 2):

The logic input pin of MAX383 is an high impedance input port. Even if you don't use a resistor, it will only drain typically a few nano-amperes. Adding a resistor may negatively affect the switching performance on the other hand. So, you shouldn't use a current limiting resistor in your circuit.

[image]